# What is the recommended way to use \everypar now that LaTeX has hooks?

Tags: lthooks, everypar

Now that LaTeX has hooks, there is a recommendation to use the hooks interface for everypar? How should this be done in l3 programs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{eplinenumber}
\setcounter{eplinenumber}{0}
\def\epindent{3cm}
\def\inscriptionprefix{Line:\hskip3pt}
\cs_set:Npn \mymod #1 #2 {\int_mod:nn{#1}{#2}}
\def\step_mod{5}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{inscription}{}
{
\let\annumber\empty
\expandafter\parindent\epindent
\bigskip
\obeylines
\everypar{
   { \stepcounter{eplinenumber}
    \ifnum\mymod{\theeplinenumber}{\step_mod}=0           \edef\annumber{\llap{\inscriptionprefix\theeplinenumber\hskip2pt}}\fi
    \ifnum\theeplinenumber=0 \edef\annumber{}\fi
    \ifnum\theeplinenumber=1 
      \edef\annumber{\llap{\inscriptionprefix\theeplinenumber\hskip2pt}}
    \fi
    \annumber
   }
  %}
 }
}
{\bigskip\setcounter{eplinenumber}{0}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{inscription}
L(ucius) Albinius f(ilius)] 
[cum Galli ob]siderent Capitolium 
[virgines Ve]stales Caere deduxit 
[ibi sacra at]que ritus sollemnes ne  
[intermitte]rentur curai sibi habuit 
[urbe recup]erata sacra et virgines 
[Romam rev]
\end{inscription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please stick to the expl3 conventions when naming functions and variables.

Comment: Unrelated but the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\parindent\epindent` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please respect `expl3` naming conventions and avoid `\cs_set` for functions not previously declared.

I don't know that this is 'the recommended way', but it uses the hooks documented in `ltpara` and is informed to some extent by the examples in section 2.3. But note that the section warns the examples are insufficiently careful for production use and that the code below is less careful than the examples.

Kant provides a minimal check that I've successfully removed the code from the hook.

[image: 'l3' inscription]

Note that I couldn't find a way to insert code at precisely the same point, so I altered the paragraph indent box, which is documented as available for modification in paragraph hooks.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702496/
% i gwestiwn Yiannis Lazarides: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702429/
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_lazarides_epindent_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_lazarides_epindent_dim { 3cm }

\int_new:N \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int
\int_gzero:N \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int
\int_new:N \l_lazarides_modstep_int
\int_set:Nn \l_lazarides_modstep_int { 5 }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \lazarides_inscriptionprefix:n {
  \hbox_gset:Nn \g_para_indent_box 
  {
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_lazarides_epindent_dim }  
    \hbox_overlap_left:n   
    {
      Line : \skip_horizontal:n { 3pt}
      \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
      \skip_horizontal:n { 2pt }
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{inscription}{}
{
  \dim_set_eq:NN \parindent \l_lazarides_epindent_dim
  \bigskip
  \obeylines
  \AddToHook { para / begin } [ lazarides ]
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int
    \int_compare:nNnTF
    {
      \int_mod:nn { \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int } { \l_lazarides_modstep_int }
    } = { 0 }
    {
      \lazarides_inscriptionprefix:n { \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int } 
    }{
      \int_compare:nNnT { \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int } = { 1 }
      {
        \lazarides_inscriptionprefix:n  { 1 } 
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  \bigskip
  \int_gzero:N \g_lazarides_eplinenumber_int
  \RemoveFromHook { para / begin }[ lazarides ]
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{inscription}
  L(ucius) Albinius f(ilius)] 
  [cum Galli ob]siderent Capitolium 
  [virgines Ve]stales Caere deduxit 
  [ibi sacra at]que ritus sollemnes ne  
  [intermitte]rentur curai sibi habuit 
  [urbe recup]erata sacra et virgines 
  [Romam rev]
\end{inscription}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The code's purpose and I am sorry I did not make it clear, is to be used for epigraphy (Greek),  https://epigraphy.packhum.org/text/159. I used some Latin as not to force people to cope with Greek fonts. I use Brill. Is part of a larger piece of code I wrote some time back and wanted to do some changes.

Comment: Internally in source3, it adds the hook to `\everypar.`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Well, I didn't test with Greek ;). As I understand it the recommendation is not to use `\everypar` directly. As you say, the hooks are preferred. Do you want me to delete this? I take it I've not understood your question.

Comment: Thanks. No need to delete other than the \kant, I think it is not useful in the discussion. Read the manual 2-3 times. Main take DONOT USE `\everypar`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I've not used hooks before. I wanted a paragraph afterwards as a check that the code was removed, because the changes made are not local to the `inscription` environment. You can use `lipsum` or `blindtext` if you prefer them to `kantlipsum`.